# Best practice for displaying empty/non-empty results for a search in iOS xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface

So I want users to be able to enter a search query, and should it return an empty or non-empty result the appropriate view is displayed (shown below):

[image: mockup]

As I'm fairly new to iOS I thought about the following possible ways of implementing this. I'm not sure if any one of these is deemed as good practice or maybe another better solution exists:

1. Create two separate view controllers with their own views that will display a message for empty search results or show non-empty results respectively
2. Create a single view that will house all of the components and show/hide certain components based on whether or not the results are empty/non-empty
3. Create a single view, but programmatically implement the methods for drawing the relevant components and just initialise the VC with the respective designated initializer (one for empty and the other for non-empty results)

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to manage the empty state of tableview meaning have a single tableview and display data when available, if no data is available display a friendly message in the tableview itself.
Below is the link that will help you implement the code:
http://www.ryanwright.me/cookbook/ios/objc/uitableview/empy-table-message
There are ots of examples available on net for managing the empty state of tableview.